# How to go back 1 folder level with __dirname?

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory, path, gulp

I am using [gulp-karma](https://github.com/karma-runner/gulp-karma) and facing a simple problem but cannot seems to find what i am doing wrong .

```
gulp.task('test', function (done) {
    karma.start({
        configFile: __dirname + '..\\test\\' +'\karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
    }, done);
});
```

Here is the code i am using and i cannot seems to go 1 level back in the folder directory . When i do the above it just **append** the `..\` to the folder direcotry without going 1 level back (which is the usual use of `..\`). Following is the folder structure .

```
parent|
      test|karma.conf.js
      webapirole|gulpfile.js
```

and my folder is inside the **webapirole** folder . i want to go back 1 folder back and go inisde the **test** folder which contains the karma.conf.js file. can anyone make me understand what i am doing wrong here ?

**error i am getting**

```
[18:06:32] Starting 'tdd'...
ERROR [config]: File C:\Users\Documents\WebApiRole..\test\karma.conf.js does not exist
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i go to parent directory when using \_\_dirname?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30858775/how-do-i-go-to-parent-directory-when-using-dirname)

Answer (score 132):

**TL;DR**

Use `path.join(__dirname, '..', 'test', 'karma.conf.js')`. Prevent use of slashes.

**Long Answer**

As a lot of answers have pointed out, using `path` module is probably the best way.
However, most of the solutions here have gone back to using slashes like:

> `path.join(__dirname+'../test/karma.conf.js')`

However, by doing this, you're beating the purpose of using `path`. One uses `path` to do operations irrespective of the underlying OS (Linux, Windows etc). Just to give a bit of insight, you can do the path operations directly as string operations (like `__dirname + '../test/karma.conf.js'`. You do not do this because Linux uses forward slashes ( `/` ), Windows uses backward slashes ( `\` ). This makes your application prone to errors when you port it across operating systems.

Thus, the better way would be:

```
path.join(__dirname, '..', 'test', 'karma.conf.js')
```

And of course, coming back - prevent use of slashes in your `path.join`, instead *spread* out your params.

Comment: The design of path.join is quite intuitive, solving various cross-platform slash problems, and should be done so.

Comment: I had a server folder and a client folder, I was trying to have my express serve the static files and sendFile the index html from the dist folder in my client folder. Every other solution with __dirname didn't work for me except yours. Thank you.

Answer (score 71):

I am using (**path**) NPM for the above usage......

simply require **path** npm in js file.Then use

```
let reqPath = path.join(__dirname, '../../../');//It goes three folders or directories back from given __dirname.
```

Comment: using slashes with the path module, defeats the purpose of using `path`. 
please see @Pranav Totla's answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/61056875/14393584

Answer (score 28):

`__dirname` is just a string. you can use `../` to traverse up the folder structure and path.join to resolve the path

```
path = require('path')

configFile: path.join(__dirname, '../test/karma.conf.js'),
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use Path like this

```
const path = require('path'); 
path.join(__dirname, "../");
```

Answer (score 9):

if you are sending the path as a string,

```
configFile: path.join(__dirname+'../test/karma.conf.js'),
```

this doesn't work.

Instead you have to use a comma, (the plus sign concatenates the two strings)

```
configFile: path.join(__dirname, '../test/karma.conf.js'),
```

Answer (score 7):

from Root directory

```
(path.join(__dirname , 'views' ,'main.html')) -> will return Root:/views/main.html
```

from any sub-folder of Root

```
(path.join(__dirname , '../views/main.html')) -> same as above
```

Answer (score 7):

Like [Pranav Totla](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61056875/9270078) said, hardcode the path with forward slashes ( "/" ) or backward slashes ( "\" ) makes the application prone to errors when it came across different operating systems.

Use the built in "path" module to prevent errors.

```
// Import "path"
const path = require('path');

// To go down on the three from index.html:
path.join(__dirname, 'css', 'style.css')

// To go up on the three from style.css:
path.join(__dirname, '..', 'img', 'cat.jpg')

// Three
root/
| |_css/
| |_img/
|
|_index.html
```

Answer (score 5):

we can use path module to go back one level from the current directory

**Example:**

```
path.join(__dirname, '..', 'test', 'conf.js')

__dirname -- present directory
..        -- one level
test      -- folder name
config.js -- file (test folder inside)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try putting a `\\` before the `..\\`.

Without it, the path your generating has a folder called `WebApi...` as part of it.  You can see this in the path being output from the error message.

Like this:

```
gulp.task('test', function (done) { 
  karma.start({ configFile: __dirname + '\\..\\test\\' +'\karma.conf.js', singleRun: true }, done); 
});
```

You may also want to look into using the [path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path) library from npm.  It makes combining paths a lot easier by handling adding and removing extra path separator characters as needed.

Comment: thank you for your response . however it didn't work out . this is the output i am getting for that  `ERROR [config]: File C:\Users\Documents\WebApiRole\..\test\karma.conf.js does not exist!`
as you can see it still considers ..\ as part of the path string

Answer (score 2):

Here is all you need to know about relative file paths:

Starting with / returns to the root directory and starts there

Starting with ../ moves one directory backward and starts there

Starting with ../../ moves two directories backward and starts there (and so on...)

To move forward, just start with the first sub directory and keep moving forward.

Answer (score 2):

this will move you 2 directory back irrespective of any operating system:

```
import { join, sep } from 'path';
join(__dirname, sep, "..", sep, "..");
```