# How do i go to parent directory when using __dirname?

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory, gulp, gulp-karma

**Directory structure :**

- WebApiRole

  - GulpFile.js
- test

  - Karma.conf.js

Gulp code from **GulpFile.js**

```
gulp.task('test', function (done) {
    karma.start({
        configFile: _configFile: __dirname + '\\..\\test\\karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
    }, done);
});
```

So my problem going to the parent directory and access the **karma.conf.js** . For some reason the path is not get resolved with `..\\` to go back to the parent directory of WebApiRole . can someone point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had to use `path` package to resolve this issue .

```
var path = require("path"),
    fs = require("fs");

gulp.task('test', function (done) {
    karma.start({
        configFile: fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, '../test/', 'karma.conf.js')),
        singleRun: true
    }, done);
});
```